# Apply a function on each row

Tags: python

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
j                 json_data                                         url
0   <div class="responsive-table">\n ...    https://www.markt.co.uk/data/...
1   <div class="responsive-table">\n ...    https://www.markt.co.uk/data/...
2   <div class="responsive-table">\n ...    https://www.markt.co.uk/data/..
```

I want to read the table from the json data using `pd.read_html()` for each row and store these results as an extra column, for example:

```
j                 json_data                                         url         table          
0   <div class="responsive-table">\n ...    https://www.markt.co.uk/data/...    ...   
1   <div class="responsive-table">\n ...    https://www.markt.co.uk/data/...    ...     
2   <div class="responsive-table">\n ...    https://www.markt.co.uk/data/...    ...
```

What I have tried:

```
def parse(data):
    #table_statistics = []
    for i in data:
        statistics = pd.read_html(i)
    return(statistics)

data_json['table'] = data_json.json_data.apply(parse)
```

However I get the following error:

> ParserError: Document is empty

When I run the following code:

```
table_statistics = []
for i in data_json.json_data.values:
     statistics = pd.read_html(i)
     table_statistics.append(statistics)
```

The output is fine and I get tables

Comment: print `df.head().to_dict()` and add it to the question, you currently have partial value for the columns.

Comment: @ThePyGuy The print out is still much too large!

Comment: `print(df.head(1).to_dict())`

Comment: @ThePyGuy It's still much too large!